# Pass a value to closure function in PHP

Tags: php, laravel, function, laravel-5

My code to send mail is

```
    public function handle(UserFollowed $event)
{
    $h = new \Acme\Helpers\functions();
    $email = $h->getUserEmail($event->followed);

    Mail::raw('Hi, welcome user!', function ($message) {
        $message->to($email)
            ->subject("New follower :)");
    });

}
```

which is working perfectly fine. The only issue is i can't use `$email` variable inside the function `Mail::raw`.

Can you suggest a solution. I would be glad to know what these sort of expressions are called

p.s. i have tried `function ($message, $email)` but it does not work. if i use a string instead of $email in `to($email)`, it works perfectly fine.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Did you try to use `use`?

```
public function handle(UserFollowed $event)
{
    $h = new \Acme\Helpers\functions();
    $email = $h->getUserEmail($event->followed);

    Mail::raw('Hi, welcome user!', function ($message) use ($email) {
        $message->to($email)
            ->subject("New follower :)");
    });

}
```

Comment: it worked, quite quick :) wot are these type of functions called? and why they r different from normal functions?

Comment: @Eirtaza - here you can read more about it: [anonymous functions](http://php.net/manual/en/functions.anonymous.php#example-165) 
It is not that different from "normal" functions, they can't see variables from parents scope too. Different is only the usage of anonymous closures, that's why the syntax is different.

Answer (score 3):

You can pass additional arguments to a closure via `use`

```
Mail::raw('Hi, welcome user!', function ($message) use ($email) {
    $message->to($email)
        ->subject("New follower :)");
});
```